# Redirect to Homeurl after post form submit on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I managed to make a frontend post submission form for users to create post.
so after click on submit it stays on the same page.
i need to redirect to home url after the post submit.
here is my code.

```
  <main class="main-content">
    <div class="add-question">
    <div class="phdr">Add Post</div>
    <div class="question-form">
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="mainForm" action="">
      <div id="singleinput">
      <label></label>
      <input type="text" name="postTitle" class="postTitle" placeholder="What’s your Post title?."/>
      </div>

      <div id="singleinput">
      <label>Description: </label>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="20" class="postContent" name="postContent" placeholder="Tell us more about your Post"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div id="singleinput">
  <label for="cat">Type:</label>
  <?php wp_dropdown_categories(       'tab_index=10&taxonomy=category&hide_empty=0' ); ?>
      </div>

<div id="singleinput">
<label>Tags</label>
<input type="text" name="postTags" class="postTags" placeholder="e.g. (abcd,efgh)"/>
</div>

      <div id="singleinput">
        <input type="submit" name="add_post" id="add_post" value="Post">
      </div>
    </form>
  <?php

  if($_POST['add_post']){

  wp_insert_post(array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_title' => $_POST['postTitle'],
  'post_content' => $_POST['postContent'],
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'post_category'   =>  array($_POST['cat']),
  'tags_input'  =>  $_POST['postTags'],
  ));
  }
  ?>
  </div>
  </div>
  </main>
```

tnx in advance

**EDIT::**

```
<?php

if($_POST['add_post']){
$post_information = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_title' => $_POST['postTitle'],
    'post_content' => $_POST['postContent'],
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_category' =>  array($_POST['cat']),
    'tags_input'    =>  $_POST['postTags'],
    );
    $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_information);
    global $wpdb;
    $redirect_link = get_home_url();
    wp_redirect($redirect_link);
}
get_header(); ?>
```

This code did the job..
Thanks Everyone!

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_POST['add_post']){
    $post_data = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_title' => $_POST['postTitle'],
    'post_content' => $_POST['postContent'],
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_category'   =>  array($_POST['cat']),
    'tags_input'  =>  $_POST['postTags'],
  );
  $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );
  if($post_id){
    $homrurl = get_home_url();
    header('Location: '$homrurl);
  }
  }
```

Comment: its says Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\qanda\wp-includes\rest-api.php:769)

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line after **wp_insert_post** function `wp_redirect(home_url());`

Comment: its says Warning: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\qanda\wp-includes\rest-api.php:769) in C:\xampp\htdocs\qanda\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1251.. same thing with the others

Comment: make sure you don't have empty lines or space before `<?php` at top of your file.

Comment: no. its clear..actually i got the solution few sec ago..i just had to put get_header after all code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure there is no error. If it is a successful insertion, you can use `header("Location:")`, otherwise, you should inform that has occurred an error:

```
if(isset($_POST['add_post'])){
    $result = wp_insert_post(array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_title' => $_POST['postTitle'],
        'post_content' => $_POST['postContent'],
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_category'   =>  array($_POST['cat']),
        'tags_input'  =>  $_POST['postTags'],
    ));
    if($result > 0 && !is_wp_error($result)){
        header("Location:" . get_home_url());
        exit();
    } else {
        echo '<script>alert("The post could not be saved")</script>';
    }
}
```

Comment: its shows a warning: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\qanda\wp-includes\rest-api.php:769). any solution??